# Joi Validation: How to make values in nested json optional?

Tags: javascript, json, nested, joi

So I have a nested json something like below, which is a payload structure for api that I am writing

```
{"item_id":"1245",
"item_name":"asdffd",
"item_Code":"1244",
"attributes":[{"id":"it1","value":"1"},{"id":"it2","value":"1"}],
"itemUUID":"03741a30-3d62-11e8-b68b-17ec7a13337"}
```

My Joi validation on the payload is :

```
validate: {
                    payload: Joi.object({
                        item_id: Joi.string().required(),
                        item_name: Joi.string().required(),
                        placeId: Joi.string().allow('').allow(null),
                        itemUUID: Joi.string().allow('').allow(null),
                        item_Code: Joi.string().required().allow(null),
                        attributes: Joi.alternatives().try(attributeObjectSchema, attributesArraySchema).optional()
                    })
                }
```

where

```
const attributeObjectSchema = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string().optional(),
    value: Joi.string().optional()
}).optional();
```

and

```
const attributeArraySchema = Joi.array().items(customAttributeObjectSchema).optional();
```

My question is : 
With the above Joi validation, if I edit my payload and send my attributes tag like below (i,e., with "values" as empty)

```
"attributes":[{"id":"CA1","value":""},{"id":"CA2","value":""}]
```

It throws an error saying:

```
"message": "child \"attributes\" fails because [\"attributes\" must be an object, \"attributes\" at position 0 fails because [child \"value\" fails because [\"value\" is not allowed to be empty]]]",
  "validation": {
    "source": "payload",
    "keys": [
      "attributes",
      "attributes.0.value"
    ]
```

What am I doing wrong here? What do I need to do if I need Joi to accept the below:

```
 "attributes":[{"id":"CA1","value":""},{"id":"CA2","value":""}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this by Changing the following schema definition from

```
const attributeObjectSchema = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string().optional(),
    value: Joi.string().optional()
}).optional();
```

To

```
const attributeObjectSchema = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string().optional(),
    value: Joi.string().allow('').allow(null)
}).optional();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
attributeArraySchema.customAttributes = [];
attributeArraySchema.customAttributes = [
    {"id":"CA1","value":""},
    {"id":"CA2","value":""}
];
```

Comment: first declare a key with blank array then assign that key data simplest way to add custom keys in object